# How to load ajax responses using Deffered

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

how to load ajax responses using Deffered. I have page which calls function ajaxCalculate onLoad, which prepares div for ajax results, then calls n of ajax requests which asks for price of products using SOAP,  and it takes much time so I want to deal it asynchronous. (n is number of products). When result will come it should be put to unused div. Ho to do it?
I started it doing in success calback, but it doesn´t worked. Please help me ho to do it with deffered object. I read that it´s better way, but I don´t know ho to do it.

```
function ajaxCalculate(numberOfProducts) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        for (i = 0; i < numberOfProducts; i++) {
            var loadingDiv = '<a href="#" class="list-group-item notloaded">' +
                '<img src = "img/loading.gif" alt = "loading"></a>';
            $(".results").append(loadingDiv);
        }
for (i = 0; i < numberOfProducts; i++) {
        var result = $.ajax({
            url: '/calculations/ajaxCalculate',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST'
         success: function(){
  $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                console.log(index);
                var result = '<a href="#" class="list-group-item">' +
                    '<span class="badge">' + item.price + '€</span>' + item.name + '</a>';
                console.log(result);
                $('.results:nth-child(?)').replaceWith(result);
            });
}
        }));
    }
```

Comment: if you call a ajax on page load why use ajax at all?

Comment: Because I want to deal with it asynchrounous way. ajax is calling soap requests which takes a lot of time.

Comment: what do you mean by asynchrounous way?

Comment: I don´t want to wait when all requests will be responded, I want to process them one by one

Comment: they will be processed one by one

Comment: what's this `results:nth-child(?)`?

Comment: here I´m replacing loading div with result but I don´t know to determine index which to use